# Ionic 4 Access to XMLHttpRequest at

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Saludo Buenas tardes, tengo un servicio hecho en php con codeigniter  hasta ahi todo bien los estube probando en Postman y funciona al 100% pero cuando intento consumir este servicio desde una aplicacion hecha en Ionic 4 enviándole algunos parametros en el Header tengo el Siguiente problema.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://192.168.1.112:33/sblwebservice/index.php/Loterias' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
>   HTTP ok status.

Este es mi codigo en el servicio web

```html
<?php

use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;

defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';
require APPPATH . 'libraries/Format.php';


class Loterias extends REST_Controller
{

    public function __construct($config = 'rest')
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Accept: application/json');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        // $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        // if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
        //     die();
        // }
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    }
    public function index_get($id = 0)
    {
        //Si no se Logra Autenticar Entonces No Siqgue
        if (!($this->Autenticate())) {
            $this->response(array('Code' => '401', 'Data' => NULL, 'Message' => 'Acceso no Autorizado'), 401);
            return;
        }
        //Obtengo el IdEmpresa
        $IdEmpresa = $this->_head_args['IdEmpresa'];
        $this->load->database();
        $masquery = ($id == 0) ? " ;" : " and IdLoteria=$id;";
        $data = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM loterias where IdEmpresa=$IdEmpresa $masquery");

        $datosResults = array();
        foreach ($data->result() as $row) {
            $fila = array(
                'IdLoteria' => (int) $row->IdLoteria,
                'NombreLoteria' => $row->NombreLoteria,
                'HrCierre' => $row->HrCierre,
                'PagarxQuiniela' => (float) $row->PagarxQuiniela,
                'PagarxPale' => (float) $row->PagarxPale,
                'IdEmpresa' => (int) $row->IdEmpresa
            );
            array_push($datosResults, $fila);
        }
        //Response Data 
        $this->response(array('Code' => '200', 'Data' => $datosResults, 'Message' => 'success'), 200);
        return;
    }
   }
```

Este es mi codigo para invocar la peticion http

```js
callOtherDomain(Endpoint:string) {
  var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = environment.UrlBase+Endpoint;
  if(invocation) {    
    invocation.open('GET', url, true); 
    invocation.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    invocation.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    invocation.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    invocation.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");

    invocation.setRequestHeader("Accept", 'application/json');
  // invocation.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
  // invocation.setRequestHeader('TokenAcces',environment.TokenAcces );
  // invocation.setRequestHeader('IdUsuario', environment.IdUsuario);
  // invocation.setRequestHeader('IdEmpresa', environment.IdEmpresa );
   
    invocation.onreadystatechange = (res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      
    };
    invocation.send(); 
  }
```

Comment: Hola JOSE que ha pasado??? pudo resolverlo... yo tengo el mismo problema...

Ionic (Angular) con Codeigniter :(

Comment: Hola Carlos, nada no encontre solución por ningún lago al final de cuentas solté ese proyecto y lo estoy haciendo con xamarin forms y .net core + EntityFramework